# Optimizing a kind-of-correlation computation

Tags: matlab, correlation

I have some code that currently reads:

```
data = repmat(1:10, 1, 2);
N = 6;
period = 10;

result = NaN * zeros(1, period);
for i=1:period
    range_indices = i:i+N;
    temp_data = data(range_indices);
    result(i) = sum( temp_data .* fliplr(temp_data));
end
```

I'm trying to make this faster (for larger datasets, e.g. period = 2000 and N = 1600), but I'm unable to get this into a form where it's a matrix operation (e.g. by using conv or xcorr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to completely linearise this. Firstly, consider the `range_indices`. These have the form:

```
1 -> N
2 -> N+1
...
P -> N+P
```

where P is the period. We can set up a matrix of these values like so:

```
range_indices = bsxfun(@plus,1:N,(1:period)'-1);
```

We can use these to grab the data directly, like so:

```
temp_data = data(range_indices);
```

It is then fairly simply to complete the function:

```
result = sum(temp_data.*fliplr(temp_data));
```

Finally, this isn't really related to the question, but just something I thought I'd point out - in future if you need to generate a matrix of NaN values, you should use `nan(1,period)` instead.

Comment: `bsxfun` is so much FUN!

Comment: Of course, thanks.. I needed `sum(.. , 2)`, and `1:period+1` in the bsxfun call, and then results were the same (and much faster).